# Is it possible to render two images (perspectives) in a retail game through code?

Tags: c++, windows, directx

This might be a bit of a stretch but just wanted to check before I try to find a different solution. The game I mean is Skyrim and I would like to record this game simultaneously from two perspectives. Is there a way to do this or am I just asking for the moon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly ten years ago nVidia had stereo shutter goggles that came with a special graphics driver which would double all renderings with slightly offset camera positions.

So yes, it is possible via code, principally. However I am not sure how far you can get by writing your own device driver or reverse engineering existing ones (afaik, there is stereoscopic rendering in OSS drivers).

edit: FYI: http://www.nvidia.com/object/stereo_3D_181.25.html

Comment: So is this a viable approach - first find the way the game is telling the directx driver (or whatever its called) to render the current image (via reverse engineering and api look up), figure out the variables its using, add a second rendering instruction with the necessary offset in game world space, get the 2 images and voila.

Comment: @user836045: But I seriously think it's not easy. You would somehow have to hook into several places or write your own device driver.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I have never reverse engineered before, so I am not going to jump into it now, maybe some time soon when I am more free to mess about.

Comment: @user836045: But note that in some parts of the world, reverse engineering might be considered an illegal act.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this with the Skyrim creation kit, but it's not out will January 2012.